# Eclipse-ADT issues about No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, android-image, eclipse-adt

I am using eclipse Juno and i added adt with it.While cleaning the project i get a lot of errors inside the console.Can anyone help me.any help will be highly appreciated.

The console is given below

```
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:79: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:83: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:25: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:33: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:37: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:65: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:69: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:45: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:49: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:53: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:57: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:61: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:178: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:182: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:113: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:115: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:110: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:107: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView.DropDown'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:121: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:126: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListPopupWindow'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:138: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:143: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:129: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:132: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.PopupMenu'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:146: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:150: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:154: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:158: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:164: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:168: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:172: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:174: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:93: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Toolbar.Button.Navigation'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:97: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:101: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:62: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:20: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:28: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:30: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:32: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:34: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:38: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:40: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:42: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:60: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:46: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:48: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:50: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:52: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:54: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:56: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:58: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:31: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Dialog'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v11/themes_base.xml:338: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v14/themes_base.xml:29: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v11/themes_base.xml:345: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v14/themes_base.xml:37: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v11/themes_base.xml:352: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v14/themes_base.xml:45: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v11/themes_base.xml:359: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v14/themes_base.xml:53: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:202: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:212: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Light'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:205: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:219: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.ActionBar'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:223: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:81: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:83: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:84: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:82: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:79: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:80: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:118: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:120: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:121: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:119: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:116: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:117: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:155: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:157: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:158: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:156: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:153: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:154: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:192: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:194: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:195: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:193: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:190: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2014-12-29 10:07:23 - Image] /mnt/D/workspaceinnerimage1/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:191: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
```

Thease are the errors that i am getting.I have already eclipse in my hand so i just downloaded ADT and append it with that.
Advance Thanks......

Comment: Please do check your R.JAVA File ....

Comment: Your R.java might have not generated. This causes such problem.

Comment: This question might seem odd: But after the build is done, does everything compile? A common situation where eclipse was building projects in the wrong order, so errors showed up while it was cleaning, but after it built, there were no errors.

Comment: May be these are some adt issues.I thought we need using proper ADT basically for genereating R.java.I have appended ADT with my eclipse Juno.My problem is that for luna only that Adt supports or can i degraded its version to Juno? Thankyou all for your answers

Comment: check if your SDK manager has **android-21** SDK installed

Comment: thankyou Alex for your comment.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I myself found the solution for this, just upgraded the version to Eclipse Luna and reinstalled SDK manager.Inside that installed API20 ie Android 4.4w.2.Now all are working fine.
Thankyou for all who replied.....